# Does map()/mapPartition() output record count should be matching with input record count?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I have a dataset of 100 records partitioned into 10 partitions and if I run mapPartition function over it, does the output dataset size has to be 100? Or can I have more than 100 records in it? (like flatmap)
Sample code :

```
Dataset<Ledger> ledger = balance.mapPartitions(new customTransformationFunction(config)),
                Encoders.bean(Ledger.class));
```

Can the size of ledger dataset be more than 100?

Comment: The Map method converts each element of source RDD into each element of result RDD by applying function. MapPartition return a new RDD by applying a function to each partition of this RDD.

Comment: MapPartition is called once for earch partition so it is faster than map function.After applying the MapPartition function ,you will have more than 100 records.In case of map function,the output would be same as input

Comment: So, mapPartition can return more than input record count?